# How to add red asterisk in label of TextField In Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to add red asterisk in label of TextFormField In Flutter[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can achieve that kind of styling in flutter.

```
TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Ciao',
                  suffixText: '*',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: it is not work,i mean for lable

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RichText for your label text

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    label: Text.rich(TextSpan(children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'ThisIsLabelText'),
      TextSpan(text: ' *', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
    ]))
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use above answer its working like a charm. I am writing the same solution again. use this this will work.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    label: Text.rich(TextSpan(children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'ThisIsLabelText'),
      TextSpan(text: ' *', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
    ]))
  ),
```

Comment: Welcome to SF :) Please dont copy answers